# Node HTTP resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, dns, request

So you can make a node HTTP GET request like so:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
  host: 'stackoverflow.com',
};

var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
});
```

I want to see what IP address that `http.get` is going to? How does the node HTTP lib determine which IP address to use if a given DNS resolves to multiple IPs?

By multiple IPs i mean something like:

```
dig +short stackoverflow.com
151.101.129.69
151.101.1.69
151.101.193.69
151.101.65.6
```

Does the [node request](https://github.com/request/request) lib differ?

Comment: what do you mean by "DNS resolves to multiple IPs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `req` object should have a `connection` object on it, which will have the remote address of the server you were connected to.

```
req.connection.remoteAddress
```

Of course, you need to wait until you actually have a connection, so I would just use the `connect` event which has what you need.  Untested, but try this:

```
req.on('connect', (res, socket, head) => {
  console.log(socket.remoteAddress);
});
```

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_remoteaddress

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In node 6.x.x as far as I understand it comes down too:

1. **http** module uses
2. **net** module uses
3. **dns** module uses
4. native module **libuv#getaddrinfo** (http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/dns.html#c.uv_getaddrinfo)

And specifically your questions which IP to use:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cd439465cc8b408eb88822c7695def611acfaaf7/lib/dns.js#L82

Very straightforward algorithm which goes like: "If multiple IP addresses are present take first one" :)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem though.  Multiple DNS lookups can result in different responses.

Comment: Thanks! The source explains a lot. That's a bad algorithm :(